# Node edit form: edit or new state?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

What's the best way of figuring out if a node form is in a Create New Node state or Edit Existing Node state?

Is there anything in the `$form` array or do I have to kludge this with `arg()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you asking for the node edit form?  If so, you can either do the following:

```
if (empty($form['nid']['#value'])) {
  // in add form
} else {
  // in edit form
}
```

Or...

```
if (arg(1) == "add") {
  // in add form...
} else {
  // in edit form...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

best way in my option is to check if the form has an NID.